# Testing web extension in CI with cypress

Tags: google-chrome-extension, continuous-integration, cypress

I want to add E2E tests to my web extension, using cypress, and run them on a CI.

Is that even possible?

The tests pass locally on `$ cypress open`, but fail on `$cypress run`

The extension adds an element to the dom and cypress can't find it (the extension doesn't seem to get loaded in headless mode)

Here's a reproducible repo with the most simple one line test:
https://github.com/goldylucks/cypress-test-tiny

Comment: What is the error? You have to describe it a little bit more.

Comment: Can't imagine this. You can run the `run`-mode with `--headed` to see what happens. Maybe that helps.